# gentoo zlib removed = portage corrupted

Tags: gentoo

Hello I'm using gentoo not for a long time and have made such mistake:
I've removed zlib package from system.
Now i've got my portage system corrupted:

```
# emerge --sync
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/emerge", line 36, in <module>
    from _emerge.main import emerge_main
  File "/usr/lib64/portage/pym/_emerge/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    from _emerge.actions import action_config, action_sync, action_metadata, \
  File "/usr/lib64/portage/pym/_emerge/actions.py", line 44, in <module>
    from _emerge.depgraph import backtrack_depgraph, depgraph, resume_depgraph
  File "/usr/lib64/portage/pym/_emerge/depgraph.py", line 40, in <module>
    from _emerge.FakeVartree import FakeVartree
  File "/usr/lib64/portage/pym/_emerge/FakeVartree.py", line 11, in <module>
    from portage.dbapi.vartree import vartree
  File "/usr/lib64/portage/pym/portage/dbapi/vartree.py", line 56, in <module>
    import re, shutil, stat, errno, copy, subprocess
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 430, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1258, in <module>
    import binascii as _binascii
ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I reinstall zlib package and repair system?

**updated**

Problem solved. 
I've copied object file `/lib/libz.so.1` from other machine and then I can run `emerge` and install `zlib` package in normal way.

Thanks to `PowerSp00n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you can download the stage3 file used for installation and restore the missing files. When `emerge` is working again reinstall `zlib` with `emerge -av1 zlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-built binary packages are available on http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/ — check it out next time you run into a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Also when you remove packages, I suggest using `emerge -pv --depclean pkgname` because it won't let you unmerge a package if things depend on it.